# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function error when pulling data from backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, axios

I am trying to pull data from my Postgresql tables to display as form fields in my React front-end. I am getting the below error message for each of the five fields (I have only included the example code for one as they are all the same).

The error is flagging in the action page and I can't see where I am going wrong as I have used similar elsewhere in my application and it worked correctly (although I am relatively new to JS / React).

error message

```
1 of 5 errors on the page
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function
pullCurrentFields/<
sustainable-scuba-web-app/src/actions/formData.action.js:23
```

**Front-end**

formData.action.js

```
import {
    diveCurrentFields,
    diveRegionFields,
    diveSpotFields,
    diveTypeFields,
    diveVisibilityFields
} from "../services/formFields.service";
import { failed_data_load, set_message, data_load_successful } from "./types.action";

export const pullCurrentFields = (dispatch) => {
    return diveCurrentFields().then(
        (response) => {
            return response;
        },
        (error) => {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();

            dispatch({
                type: failed_data_load,
            });

            dispatch({
                type: set_message,
                payload: message,
            });

            return Promise.reject();
        }
    );
};
```

formFields.service.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = "http://localhost:5002/api/formfields/";

// posts register details to backend

export const diveCurrentFields = (currentList) => {
        return axios.get(API_URL + "divecurrentfields", {
            //currentList,
        });
    };
```

**Backend**

formFields.routes.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const controller = require("../../controllers/formFields.controller");


module.exports = function(app) {

// return list fields for dive log form
    app.get('/api/formfields/divecurrentfields', controller.allCurrentFields());
};
```

formFields.controller.js

```
const db = require("../server/models/");
const currents = db.currentLevel;
const diveRegions = db.diveRegion;
const diveTypes = db.diveType;
const visibilityLevels = db.visibilityLevel;
const diveSpots = db.diveSpot;

exports.allCurrentFields = (req, res) => {

    currents.findAll({})
        .then((currents) => {

            const currentList = [];
            for (i = 0; i < currents.length; i++) {
                currentList.push(currents[i].dataValues);
            }
            if (!currents) {
                return res.status(404).send({ message: "No current levels stored" });
            }

            res.status(200).send({
                data: currentList,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
};
```